# I need to UPDATE the data in one column using the data from another tables column

Tags: php, sqlite

I've followed lots of examples and search for a solution that works for me but none has worked.

This is my query

```
  UPDATE resultados 
  SET respuesta_r = (SELECT examenes.respuesta FROM examenes WHERE examenes.tipo='final' AND examenes.nivel='2') 
  WHERE resultados.orden_p = examenes.orden AND examenes.tipo='final' AND examenes.nivel='2'
```

It's an SQLite database, I tried many types of sorting, but here I have had no luck jet. Sorry it's all in Spanish. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct SQL will be:

```
 UPDATE resultados 
  SET respuesta_r = (SELECT examenes.respuesta FROM examenes 
                      WHERE examenes.tipo='final' AND examenes.nivel='2' 
                            AND resultados.orden_p = examenes.orden)
```

but if select returns multiple rows, you can use aggregate function like:

```
 UPDATE resultados 
  SET respuesta_r = (SELECT MIN(examenes.respuesta) FROM examenes 
                        WHERE examenes.tipo='final' AND examenes.nivel='2'
                              AND resultados.orden_p = examenes.orden)
```

Comment: Thank You so much Giga Kokaia, It worked incredibly fast and beautifully. :-)